# Question about Alternating forms

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, differential-forms

[image]

So I understand the definition of an alternating form on $\mathbb{R}^m$, but I don't really understand the proof of the lemma. Could someone explain the first observation?  Why is it so?

Comment: (1) is the generalization of the observation that $dx^i(e_j)=1$ if $i=j$ and $=0$ otherwise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint for (1):** Consider $e_{j_1} = (0, \dots, 0, 1, 0, \dots, 0)$ where the $1$ appears in the $j_1^{\ \text{th}}$ entry. As per the definition of $dx^I$, we need to know what $e_{j_1}^{i_1}, \dots, e_{j_1}^{i_k}$ are as they form the entries in the first row of the matrix. Almost all the components of $e_{j_1}$ are zero, the only one which isn't is $e_{j_1}^{j_1}$ which is $1$. So, if $j_1$ is not one of the entries in $I$, then the first row of the matrix consists of zeroes only so $dx^I(e_{j_1}, \dots, e_{j_k}) = 0$.

The same analysis above applies to $e_{j_2}$ and the second row, $e_{j_3}$ and the third row and so on. The final piece of information you need to use is that $I, J \in \mathcal{I}_k$ which is the set of all ordered $k$-tuples with strictly increasing components.

**Hint for (2):** The implication left to right is trivial, for the other direction note that $\omega = 0 \Leftrightarrow \omega(\xi_1, \dots, \xi_k) = 0$ for all $\xi_1, \dots, \xi_k \in \mathbb{R}^m$. Use the linearity of $\omega$ to write $\omega(\xi_1, \dots, \xi_k)$ in terms of $\omega(e_{i_1}, \dots, e_{i_k})$.

Comment: I think I'm reading something wrong, because I keep taking this as $I$ and $J$ must be disjoint

Comment: You are. There is nothing there to suggest any relationship between $I$ and $J$, they are just two elements of $\mathcal{I}_k$.

Comment: Ahhhh, I understand now. Could you kindly explain (2) and (3)?

Comment: Can you give me an example of (2) and (3)?

Comment: I've added a hint for (2). You should completely finish (1) and (2) first and then consider (3) again.

Comment: you mean the fact that $$\omega ( \xi_1, \ldots , \xi_k) = \omega( \sum_{I \in \mathcal{I}_k} \alpha_I e_I , \ldots , \sum_{I \in \mathcal{I}_k} \beta_I e_I )$$ $\alpha, \beta \in \mathbb{R}$, and then obvious because $\omega$ is multi-linear? Can you give an example of an $\omega \in \Lambda^k (\mathbb{R}^m)^{*}$

Comment: because it says we may write all $\omega$'s in terms of $\omega_I$'s, but I'm not clear as to what $\omega_I$ is? Or is it just necessary to know that it's $\omega$ on some index set and nothing more?

Comment: I believe I have a good understanding of (1) and (2), but now I need to understand (3)

Comment: Yes to your first comment. The $\omega_I$'s are just real constants given by the formula $\omega_I = \omega(e_{i_1}, \dots, e_{i_k})$.

Comment: I'm just not understanding why all $\omega$ may be written in such a way.

Comment: Given what you've already done, you know that $\omega$ is entirely determined by the values $\omega(e_{i_1}, \dots, e_{i_k})$.

Comment: I see that, for example, $$\omega(\xi_1) = \omega(\sum_{I \in \mathcal{I}_k} \alpha_I e_I) = \sum_{I \in \mathcal{I_k}} \alpha_I \omega (e_I)$$, but I don't see how $$\omega = \sum_{I \in \mathcal{I}_k} \omega_I dx^{I}$$